# Express-Session creating too many sessions in DynamoDB. (Using Google One Tap)

Tags: express, session, amazon-dynamodb, google-authentication

I am using Google One Tap to log into a webpage and trying to use AWS' DynamoDB to manage the session info.  I previously tried Elasticache and couldnt view the clusters/connect to the DB, so I switched.  Now, I have the opposite problem where I'll get 20-100+ sessions saved to DyanmoDB in a 5-30 min span when I go to the login page 1-2x.  I thought the problem was having saveUninitialized set to true, but that has not changed anything.

Would really appreciate any suggestions on how to debug this/what's going on/alternatives for session management

```
const session = require('express-session')
const DynamoDBStore = require('connect-dynamodb')(session)

const options = {   
    table: 'my-sessions',   

    AWSConfigJSON: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESSKEYID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY,
            region: 'us-east'
    }
}

app.use(session({
    genid: (req) => {
        return uuidv4() // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },
        cookie: {
         secure: true
},
    store: new DynamoDBStore(options), 
    secret: 'mysecretkey',
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 5*60*1000, //set to 5 min 
    },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    name: 'id',
    rolling: true
}));
```

Edit: Adding my Google Auth process just in case I modified it/managing sessions incorrectly

This function is on the client side and runs once the user selects the profile to log in with

```
function handleCredentialResponse(response) {         
    var id_token = response.credential;       
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/auth');  // have been getting a 404 error in the console, but I get logs in the terminal that indicate /auth was reached?  secondary, but would love any insight into this
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
        };
    xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
}
```

This is on the server side, and what a POST req to /auth hits:

```
const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);

exports.authLogin = (req, res, next) => {   

    async function verify() {
    
        // google API function that verifies the JWT signature, the aud claim, the exp claim, and the iss claim.
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: req.body.idtoken, // passed from handleCredentialResponse function
            audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,  
        });

        const payload = ticket.getPayload();
        const userid = payload['sub'];
        req.session.user = userid
        req.session.auth = true // logged in 
        req.session.save()
        
    }
    verify().catch(console.error);
    
    next()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following everything you're asking here, but I do see an implementation mistake that could create problems.  In your `exports.authLogin()` function, you are calling `next()` before the asynchronous portion of your middleware has finished.  Instead, you should do this:

```
exports.authLogin = (req, res, next) => {   

    async function verify() {
    
        // google API function that verifies the JWT signature, the aud claim, the exp claim, and the iss claim.
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: req.body.idtoken, // passed from handleCredentialResponse function
            audience: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,  
        });

        const payload = ticket.getPayload();
        const userid = payload['sub'];
        req.session.user = userid
        req.session.auth = true // logged in 
        req.session.save()
        
    }
    verify().then(next).catch(err => {
         console.error(err);
         next(err);
    });
}
```

This moves the call to `next()` into a `.then()` handler so it does not advance to the next request handler in the chain until after `verify()` is done.  In addition, if `verify()` fails, it also calls `next(err)` rather than just doing nothing but logging and leaving the current request stranded.

I also note that you aren't waiting for `req.session.save()` to complete before proceeding so you need to figure out if that is also something you need to do.

Comment: thanks for catching that.  I made the change and it's still doing it.  I added a console.log to here below and noticed it's printing like 20 times.  Not sure what to google/how to go about debugging, any ideas?
app.use(session({
    genid: (req) => {
       console.log('gen id');
        return uuidv4() // use UUIDs for session IDs
    },...

Comment: @user3768258 - At the start of your `authLogin()` function, add this:  `console.log("authLogin(): path=", req.path)` so you can at least see what requests are causing it to get called so many times.

Comment: @user3768258 - You can also add this as the first middleware: `app.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("start: path=", req.path); next();});`

Comment: When I added these logs, most of the time, nothing extra came up.  But sometimes (I think it's when my laptop falls asleep), I get this multiple times: 
start: path= /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
start: path= /apple-touch-icon.png
start: path= /favicon.ico
Confused bc I'm on a laptop...I can only guess it's some weird new M1 mac thing??  any ideas?

Comment: @user3768258 - These are extra things an apple browser may ask for from a website.   You could make explicit routes for them and put those before your middleware and then they wouldn't get to your middleware.